# Setting up my custom nameservers to my domain with bind

Tags: dns, bind

Assume that I have the `example.com` domain registered and that I am running a bind master and slave for this domain.

I have two nameservers, let's pretend they have ip addresses 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 each with this zone config on them and my webserver is on ip 3.3.3.3.

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
        2013042201  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

        IN  NS      ns1.example.com.
        IN  NS      ns2.example.com.

ns1     IN  A       1.1.1.1
ns2     IN  A       2.2.2.2


@       IN  A       3.3.3.3
www     IN  A       3.3.3.3
```

In my Godaddy control panel, I am supposed to input ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com into the name servers.

But how will it know the ip address of my servers? My nameservers are on 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2.  But how will it know this when the domain ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com do not resolve to anything?

For example, it has to know my nameservers are hosted on 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 first in order to resolve ns1 and ns2.  But it clearly doesn't know this.  It's missing a huge very important step.

What am I supposed to do?

EDIT: Changed mydomain.com to example.com.  I wasn't aware that mydomain.com existed and that there was a domain we could use for examples.  Sorry.

Comment: downrated for lying about your domain, and using somebody else's domain instead of yours for purpose of example, rather than "example.com" or "example.net", as names set aside for example and documentation purposes

Comment: I was unaware that mydomain.com even existed, I used it as an example...  I am sorry for the confusion, but if you read my post correctly you would have noted the "assume" statement.  I never said that I owned the domain... I just said "assume that I do"  I wasn't really sure what else to write, so I just thought of "mydomain" on the spot. Is it really that much of a big deal though? I mean, this is an online forum for computer science things, not some business forum where I am trying to scam people.

Comment: yes, i read that. It is still inconsiderate to use other people's domains because you don't want to disclose your own. How wouild you like it if other people used your domain for their examples?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I apologize and I will ensure that this does not happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com will have to resolve to ip addresses, or they can't be queried. Your problem is that they are hosts of the very same zone they are authoritative for. This circular reference is broken by introducing additional referential records in parent zone, called "glue", or "glue records". These are simply A records with ip addresses of your nameservers, and added only in this special case.

Comment: Once I've added these glue records- is this what would technically happen: The client's ISP asks root where to find the TLD com which then asks where to find example.com which then tells them to go to the nameserver ns1.example.com or ns2.example.com which then resolves example.com or site1.example.com or ns1.example.com etc?

Comment: not quite. There is no need for client's ISP, because clients can query any recursive nameserver open to them, including their own. The TLD nameservers won't query, but will return names of nameservers authoritative for example.com, and additionally the ip addresses, because glue records were found. And finally, this doesn't happen for each query, because earlier replies will be cached.

Comment: Ah, so then I would not need A records for ns1 and ns2 in my zone files, right?

Comment: you need them in your zone files too - glue in parent zone is referential only, parent zone nameservers aren't authoritative. Only your ns1 and ns2 are.

Comment: Oh wow, they sure made this very confusing.  If we were to dumb it down a bit into a conversation would it go like this? Hey TLD nameserver, which nameserver is authoritative for example.com? "ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com"  Those domains are "glued" by the parent zone to my server IP.  Then the person asks my server Hey, is this the authoritative nameserver for example.com? to which the server replies '"Yes, I am ns1 at 1.1.1.1 what do you need?" The person then confirms that the parent zone for example.com gave the same answer as the authoritative nameserver,

Comment: and if all checks out, then the person can ask other questions like "Hey, where can I find one.exmple.com?"

Comment: See it from this angle:  The only thing glue changes is, when parent zone nameserver are queried for the authoritative nameservers of your zone, the answer provides the ip addresses of those authoritative nameservers in addition to their names. The rest is as usual..